# cannot set property of undefined when passing a number to a new generated array

Tags: javascript

I am writing codes to convert initial letters of each word in a sentence to upper case and the rest to lower case. When I generated a new array arr and try to pass a number to it, there would be an error.

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined.

I have no idea why this is happening.

```
function titleCase(str) {

  var word = str.split(" ");
  var arr = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++){
    arr[i][0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase();
    if(word[i].length>1)
    for(var j = 1; j<word[i].length; j++){
      arr[i][j] = word[i][j].toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  str = arr.join(' ');
  return str;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That is correct. There is no`arr[i]`. It is `undefined`. The array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` starts out as an empty array, but you try to reference (and change a property of) `arr[i]` without creating anything at `arr[i]` first:

```
arr[i][0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase();
```

To tweak your existing code, create an array *inside* the loop, change *that* array, then join it at the end and push to the outer `arr`:

```js
function titleCase(str) {

  var word = str.split(" ");
  var arr = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    let newWordArr = [];
    newWordArr[0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase();
    if (word[i].length > 1) {
      for (var j = 1; j < word[i].length; j++) {
        newWordArr.push(word[i][j].toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    arr.push(newWordArr.join(''));
  }

  str = arr.join(' ');
  return str;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

But I'd suggest using a regular expression instead: put the first non-space character into a capture group, while putting following non-space characters into a different capture group, then `.replace` with the first group `.toUpperCase()` and the second group `.toLowerCase()`:

```js
const titleCase = str => str
  .replace(
    /(\S)(\S*)/g,
    (_, g1, g2) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase()
  );

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

`(\S)` - Match and capture a single non-space character (goes into argument g1 above)

`(\S*)` - Match and capture zero or more non-space characters that follow (goes into argument g2 above)

Answer (score 1):

```
function titleCase(str) {

  var word = str.split(" ");
  var arr = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++){
    let newWord = '';
    for(var j = 0; j < word[i].length; j++){
      if(j === 0){
        newWord += word[i][j].toUpperCase();

      }
      else {
        newWord += word[i][j].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    arr.push(newWord);
  }

  str = arr.join(' ');
  return str;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only has 1-dimensional arrays, but you can build arrays of arrays...

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

```
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");

function titleCase(str) {

  var word = str.split(" ");
  var arr = new Array();

  var arr = []
  for (var i=0;i<word.length;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++){
    arr[i][0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase();
    if(word[i].length>1)
    for(var j = 1; j<word[i].length; j++){
      arr[i][j] = word[i][j].toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  str = arr.join(' ');
  return str;
}

console.log (titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **just show** this title in your style(uppercase letter in each word), you can do this by using following methods:

1. You can simply archive that by using `css`.

```css
#title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span id="title">I'm a little tea pot</span>
```

2. If you want to get this result with `javascript`, you need to do DOM operation.

```js
document.getElementById('title').style.textTransform = 'capitalize';
```

```html
<span id="title">I'm a little tea pot</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error.

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined.

This error is occurred at `arr[i][0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase()`, because `arr[i]`is undefined as you can see in my snippet.

So you need to add a new item into `arr` array by using `arr.push()` like below;

```js
function titleCase(str) {

  var word = str.split(" ");
  var arr = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++){
    console.log(`arr[${i}] is ${arr[i]}`);
    arr.push(word[i][0].toUpperCase());
    if(word[i].length>1) {
      arr[i] = `${arr[i]}${word[i].slice(1)}`;
    }
  }

  console.log(arr);
  
  return arr.join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```